# How should eMMC RPMB shared keys be stored?

Tags: security, cryptography

Storing data in the eMMC Replay Protected Memory Block (RPMB) requires use of a shared key. RPMB read/write operations utilize the shared key to generate a Hashed Message Authentication Code (HMAC).

Apparently, RPMB is intended as storage for high-value data, like DRM keys. However, this seems to present a classic "chicken and egg" scenario: securing the high-value data requires secure storage for the RPMB shared key.

If saving the shared key presupposes access to secure storage, there seems to be no point in using RPMB, as the DRM keys could be directly stored in secure storage instead.

How should the RPMB shared key be stored?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to approach it the way TEE solutions do. TEE solutions essentially claim ownership of the RPMB partition. During the initial boot (during the manufacturing process), a unique RPMB symmetric key will be derived and programmed into the eMMC/RPMB device. From that point forward and during each subsequent boot, the TEE is able to re-generate the shared key to be able to communicate with the RPMB. However, the eMMC is almost always under the control of the main operating system, such as Linux, so signing the communication messages alone is often insufficient for storing data securely in the RPMB. I.e., messages will be sent through a non-secure execution environment and therefore the data being sent to the RPMB must also be encrypted. That encryption is solely handled and controlled by the TEE environment itself.

**Edit**:
As suggested by Rohit and the bot, here [1] is a reference that explains how this is done in the open source project OP-TEE, of which I've been one of the original authors and co-maintainer [2] for about ten years.

[1] https://optee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/secure_storage.html#rpmb-secure-storage

[2] https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/master/MAINTAINERS#L303

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could improve your answer with a reference or citation.

Comment: It's also a requirement to declare your affiliation.  Which you have now done.  Hence the upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually SoCs have some API/hw feature to obtain device unique keys (usually derived ones), that can be used. Often they change when enabling Secure Boot and similar features, so you can be then sure it's only your SoC running your SE that can talk to RPMB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).